# Store address dynamic array in c

Tags: c, data-structures, pointers

I'm trying to save the address of a dynamic array index.  The last line of this function is what gives the pointer error.

```
static struct sstor *dlist
struct node *ins_llist(char *data, struct llist *l) {
    struct node *p, *q;
    q = malloc((size_t)sizeof(struct node));
    if(q == NULL)
        return(NULL);
    if(ins_list(data, &dlist))
        return NULL;
    q->item = &(dlist->item[(dlist->sz)-1]); // Problem?
    ...}
```

Allocation of dlist

```
struct llist *init_llist(void) {
    struct llist *l;
    dlist = init_list(INITSZ);
    if(dlist == NULL)
        return(NULL);
```

This is my node

```
struct node {
    char **item;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
```

This is my array

```
struct sstor {
    int sz;
    int maxsz;
    char item[][1024];
};
```

I'm still new to pointers.  The line below gives the error: assignment from incompatible pointer type

```
q->item = &(dlist->item[(dlist->sz)-1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you allocate an actual `struct node` for `q` to point to...

The "incompatible pointer types" error arises because `q->item` has type `char **` (a pointer to a pointer to char), and `&(dlist->item[...])` has type `char (*)[1024]` (a pointer to an array of 1024 char).  These types simply aren't compatible (there *is* no actual "pointer to char" object for `q->item` to point to).

You can fix the problem in two ways.  The first is by changing the declaration of `struct node` to this:

```
struct node {
  char (*item)[1024];
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;
};
```

The second is by changing both the declaration of `struct node` to this:

```
struct node {
  char *item;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;
 };
```

..and changing the assignment statement to this:

```
q->item = dlist->item[(dlist->sz)-1]; // No Problem!
```

(The first alternative makes `q->item` point to the entire array, and the second makes it point to the first `char` in the array.  The perspecacious will note that these are pointers to the same location, but with different types.  Usually, the second form is what you want).

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the node structure to char *item and fixed the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

`char**` is not the same as `char[][1024]`

Try to fix the `sstor` structure like this:

```
 struct sstor {
  int sz;
  int maxsz;
  char *item[1024];
 };
```

Comment: That would require changing the way that `struct sstor` is allocated and used - it is possible to fix the problem without altering `struct sstor`.